# is it correct about dimension table and star schema?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, olap, star-schema

is it correct dimensions of star schema also has foreign and primary key relationship ?Is it conceptually correct , please help as its confusion I am having in my Dateware implementation.
If yes then in what cases , same for No
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a dimension has a FK that relates it to another dimension, that's called a snow flake. Here is what folks on the Kimball forum have to say about it http://forum.kimballgroup.com/t460-start-schema-vs-snow-flake-schema

Snow flakes are conceptually correct, but they do add complexity so you will need to put thought into when you use them.

Comment: any tools you can suggest to make star schema with gui and aggregates as well ? I am working with sql server

Comment: You can design the data architecture of your facts and dimensions in a tool like Erwin, but you really should create the physical tables using SQL.